# Is it possible to make QML ListView cyclic?

Tags: c++, qt4, qml

I've implemented a simple list model and list delegate in QML, and now curious if it feasible to make the underlying list cyclic. 
Here is the code snippet:

```
      Common.MarketsListView {
      id: markets
      anchors.top: logoImage.bottom
      anchors.topMargin: 5
      cacheBuffer: 20000

      NumberAnimation on x {
          running: runtime.isActiveWindow
          loops: Animation.Infinite
          from: 0
          to: -300
          duration: 20000
      }
```

Currently, the list slowly moves to the left, but as it reaches the end only few last items are shown. So I shall either make the underlying list cyclic, or hard-code the jump to the first list item :(

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this with a ListView, but you may be able to get the bahavior you want using PathView, e.g. https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/declarative-ui-components-spinner.html

Comment: thanks for the link! I haven't looked at PathView yet, but yes, it seems plausible -- I've immediately remembered an example they gave us at Qt dev days -- should work!

Comment: Yes, I think pathview is what you want in this situation, it will let your cycle through your list without there being an "end" to the list.